# abstract machine, what language does M accecpt?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata

What language does M accept?

[image]

1: {a}3  ∪  {b}3  ∪  {λ}

2: {a}3  ∪  {b}3

3: {a, b}3  ∪  {λ}

4: {a, b}3  ∪  {λ}

I'm not completely sure just yet which one would work. I would appreciate it if you could also explain why it is the correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain in words what the automaton does?

Comment: It doesn't do anything, I just need to find out which equation will be accepted, (land on the double ring)

Comment: x @jackdh: It most certainly does something when you feed an input string to it.

Comment: Then I do not know I'm afraid, I've just been given this question.

Comment: x @jackdh: Hopefully the question was not given to you without some preceding explanation of how finite automata work.

Comment: Yes it was unfortunately.

Comment: x @jackdh: Then figuring out why someone is asking you questions you don't have the means to answer, and how to get them to stop doing that, should be a higher priority for you than to find the -- comparatively irrelevant -- answer to this one.

Comment: Well, yeah but unfortunately I have to pick one of those.

Answer (score 0):

In your finite automaton there are three so called **states**: $A$, $B$ and $C$. The arrows tell us how we get from one state to another, and the arrow that points to $A$ out of nowhere tells us that the automation starts in state $A$.

The automaton accepts a word if it ends in a final state. $A$ is a final state, as is has two circles around it.

If we put the empty word $\lambda$ into the automaton, the word is accepted. We don't change states at all, but we are already in the final state $A$.

If we put an $a$ or $b$ into the automaton we end up in state $B$. $B$ is not a final state, so the automaton doesn't accept the word. In fact, is has to be a bit longer. If we put another $a$ or $b$ into the automaton we end up in state $C$. Again, this is not a final state, so the word is not accepted. Putting in another $a$ or $b$ however will get us back to the final state $A$ and word is accepted.

So the automaton excepts $\{\lambda, aaa, bbb, abb, aab, aba, baa, \dots \} = \{a^p b^q \mid p+q \mod 3 = 0 \} $. Do you see what language that is?